# Get deviceToken From Any View

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, nsuserdefaults, devicetoken

In my app, I have the following flow.  When it is launched it asks about receiving Push Notifications.  If you click yes, it takes the deviceToken and stores it as a NSUserDefault.  Part of the app is making requests.  Those requests are added to an XML file, with a section for the deviceToken, so that a PHP script can later send a notification for a request, based on the deviceToken that is in the XML.

I recently implemented:

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
        [appDomain release];
```

so that a user can clear out a number of other NSUserDefaults that they may not want anymore.  The issue is that this also clears out the deviceToken.  How can I go about getting the deviceToken again, without having to use the didRegister code I have in the App Delegate?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to store the device token in your app, it may get changed from APNS and may result in the notification failure of delivery, you should just store it in a global variable and update it everytime app is launched

Comment: This is the way I am doing it, and if the app takes off big enough to where there are countless people using it, I may, but this is how it is currently setup, and I am not looking at revamping everything right now, just keeping it going.

Comment: then I guess you better use pList file for storing and updating the value